# webdriver.io selecting multiple elements and clicking one by one

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chimp.js

I'm using webdriver.io for some automated unit testing, I can select multiple elements using browser.elements

but I need to be able to click each of the selected elements

I know there's a `browser.click()` - but that would only click the first element
I've been playing with this for last 3 hours - the documentation is kind of confusing on webdriver.io about using `browser.elements`

How do I trigger each of the selected element's click?

```
var selector = '.main-section * .tbody .td:nth-child(14) a';
// this gets an awway of element id's   
var selectedButtons = browser.elements(selector);

// log returned array
console.log(selectedButtons.value);
// this prints the elementId's
console.log(selectedButtons.value[1].element().value.ELEMENT);
```

Output:

```
 [ { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-135',
    selector: '.main-section * .tbody .td:nth-child(14) a',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-135' },
    index: 0 },
  { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-136',
    selector: '.main-section * .tbody .td:nth-child(14) a',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-136' },
    index: 1 },
  { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-137',
    selector: '.main-section * .tbody .td:nth-child(14) a',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-137' },
    index: 2 },
  { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-138',
    selector: '.main-section * .tbody .td:nth-child(14) a',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.23250146411810424-138' },
    index: 3 } ]

0.23250146411810424-136
```

using webdriver.io within chimp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of webdriver-sync added the functionality so that the returned elements have the webdriver.io prototype on them - that is that you can just call `.click` on the returned elements in the array.

Version 0.45.x+ of chimp uses the latest webdriver-sync

Comment: Thanks!, I was using 0.45.0

Comment: This is great news. That is going to make life so much easier.